# difference between efficiency these sql queries?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables customer and order1. I want to know which of the following queries is more efficient

```
select cust_name,ISBN from customer,order1 where customer.cust_no=order1.cust_no;
```

,

```
select cust_name,ISBN from customer inner join order1 on customer.cust_no=order1.cust_no;
```

and

```
select cust_name,ISBN from customer natural join order1;
```

I've read that inner join takes cartesian product of two tables and then return only rows that match the 'on' condition. Does natural operates in the same way as inner join? Also how inline queries are efficient than joins?

Comment: are equal... (if there is only this join cust_no)

Comment: so they work the same way internally right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three queries should do the same thing. You could verify by checking the execution plan, but any differences between them should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> Natural joins and joins with `USING`, including outer join variants, are processed according to the SQL:2003 standard. The goal was to align the syntax and semantics of MySQL with respect to `NATURAL JOIN` and `JOIN ... USING` according to SQL:2003. However, these changes in join processing can result in different output columns for some joins. Also, some queries that appeared to work correctly in older versions (prior to 5.0.12) must be rewritten to comply with the standard.
> These changes have five main aspects:
>
> - The way that MySQL determines the result columns of `NATURAL` or `USING` join operations (and thus the result of the entire `FROM` clause).
> - Expansion of `SELECT *` and `SELECT tbl_name.*` into a list of selected columns.
> - Resolution of column names in `NATURAL` or `USING` joins.
> - Transformation of `NATURAL` or `USING` joins into `JOIN ... ON.`
> - Resolution of column names in the `ON` condition of a `JOIN ... ON.`

Also, note that:

> The *`conditional_expr`* used with `ON` is any conditional expression of the form that can be used in a `WHERE` clause. Generally, you should use the `ON` clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the `WHERE` clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set.

And finally to answer your question regarding sub queries, from [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)

> A `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not specific to MySQL Server alone. Prior to SQL-92, outer joins did not exist, so subqueries were the only way to do certain things. Today, MySQL Server and many other modern database systems offer a wide range of outer join types.